# porque não estou conseguindo puxar o style.css e bootstrap.css corretamente?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Eu criei um função para puxar os arquivos css e bootstrap no WordPress mas eles tão aparendo no final o numero de uma versão que atrapalha

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='https://meusite.com.br/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.0.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='https://meusite.com.br/wp-content/themes/cjovem/css/bootstrap.css?ver=5.0.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='https://meusite.com.br/wp-content/themes/cjovem/css/style.css?ver=5.0.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='https://api.w.org/' href='https://teste.piripiriacontece.com.br/wp-json/' />
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://meusite.com.br/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://meusite.com.br/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.0.4" />
```

**Função em PHP**

```
    // Register Script
function custom_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');



    wp_register_script( 'icones', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, false, false );


    wp_register_script( 'magnific-popup', 'css/magnific-popup.css', false, false, false );

    wp_register_script( 'Animacao', 'css/animate.css', false, false, false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```

Comment: Você pode atualizar a pergunta com o código da função `wp_enqueue_style`?

Comment: O problema deve estar no caminho para o arquivo. Só com isso que você postou não dá pra ajudar.

Comment: Bom dia amigo, acredito que seja alguma parte da função atrapalhando no caminho, mas não consigo indentificar, estou colocando o link do googlr drive com o código completo Humm [link](http://bit.ly/sitephpecss)

Comment: Olha o minuto 8:10 desse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTy77jhsMH8 Eles está mostrando como colocar os links CDN, mas os arquivos seguem o mesmo padrão.

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/219974)